# ngFor repeating Components

Tags: angular, components

I have two components one is Post:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'post',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{postText}}</p>
    `
})
export class Post {
    title : string;
    postText : string;
    constructor(title:string, postText:string) {
        this.title  = title;
        this.postText = postText;
    }
}
```

the other is newsfeed:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Post} from "./app.post.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'news-feed',
    template: `
    <h1>News Feed</h1>
    <ul *ngFor='#post of posts'>
        <li *ngFor='#post of posts'>
            {{post | json}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    `
})
export class NewsFeed {
   posts : Post[];
    constructor() {
        let p1 = new Post("Post1","Wow greate post");
        let p2 = new Post("Such Post", "WoW");
        this.posts =[];
        this.posts.push(p1);
        this.posts.push(p2);
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to repeat each post using the template in post rather than just using object syntax or formatting the post inside of the newsfeed. Perhaps I am approaching this the wrong way as I am new to ang2. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: post question clearly what you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact, Angular2 will instantiate component for you. Simply add the selector tag in your ngFor loop:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#postData of posts">
    <post [title]="postData.title"
          [postTest]="postData.postText"></post>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your post data must be defined this way:

```
posts : any[];
constructor() {
  this.posts =[];
  this.posts.push({title:"Post1",postText:"Wow greate post"});
  this.posts.push({title:"Such Post", postText:"WoW"});
}
```

For this you need to refactor a bit your component to add inputs:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'post',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{postText}}</p>
  `
})
export class Post {
  @Input() // <-----
  title : string;
  @Input() // <-----
  postText : string;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! In fact you can ;-) It would be something like that: `<post [post]="postData" ...` and in your component: `@Input() post:any;`

Comment: Hey @ThierryTemplier, do you know if it is possible to include different component in ngFor. For example like in this question let's say I have `post-text` and `post-article` compoenets and I need to do something like `<post-{{postData.type}} [post]="postData"...` inside for loop. thanks

Comment: @NoopurDabhi I think you should use *ngIf or *ngSwitch like `<post-text *ngIf="postData.type === 'text'"`... and so on. But maybe there is a better way in Angular 4/5. As many things changed since this question was asked.. (let me know if you will find it :))

Comment: I found solution... I used this [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXsIWykqKZi5r75VMtw2?p=preview) ...instead of calling button onclick function, I'm putting selector tag of components in loop, and in component, I used json same as mentioned in pluker

Comment: Beautiful answer!!